# What is the botanic equivalent to the circulatory system?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, flora, blood

There have been a few questions on mobile plants on this site and even more on their intelligence, but one that has not been asked so far is related to the lifeblood of creatures: blood. Inside of Earth plants, the circulatory system is less complex, as the organism does not need to move. But surely if they were mobile they would have a need for an effective circulatory system? What would the botanic equivalent to the animal circulatory system be?

My current thought is that the hydraulic fluid that a plant's vegetal muscle uses would be the closest thing to blood.

Next question

[Muscles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59194/what-is-the-botanic-equivalent-to-muscles)

Comment: "the plants do not need healing, immunity or the likes." - That's so false... Also, most plants do have circulatory systems already. Water with minerals up, water with sugars down.

Comment: @Mołot don't plants just grow over cuts?

Comment: That's not so simple. First, they close cuts with resin. Or cut away damaged part if it's expendable, like leaf. It's a topic for a book, not for a comment. And plants do have some defenses against bacteria and viruses. That's what GMO crops is about - to copy defenses against certain things from plants that have it to the plants that we want to eat.

Comment: @Mołot oh, I am not specialized in plant biology. I apologize.

Comment: I'm not specialized, either. I just wanted to know what creates this weird shapes I love in wood, and what's about the GMO thing. The point is, plants *do* have circulatory system, *do* have defense mechanisms against pathogens and *do* need healing. Of course, it's different from animals' ones - but they do. And in that your question is vastly inaccurate.

Comment: By the way, have you tried maple syrup? Basically, It's just a tree's blood, condensed :)

Comment: @TrEs-2b: Don't animals just grow tissue over cuts as part of the wound healing process?

Comment: Our vascular plants have phloem and xylem as transport systems (the former transports water and nutrients -minerals mostly- from the roots up to leaves while the latter transports water and nutrients -sugars mostly- from the leaves down to the root). Furthermore plants cells are all connected to their neighboors via plasmodesmata ('holes' in the cell wall) and some transport is done too that way. So plants do already have circulatory system and it is very complex (because it is much more difficult to get around the same problems animals circulatory systems encounters) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odds are it would be like the more advanced circulatory systems already on our planet. More movement means you need more resources available to cells, which means you need something better at carrying those resources than just water i.e. blood, and/or something to hasten the circulation i.e. a heart or other form of pump.

Both of these are feasible. Plants already contain sap, resin, and other fluids used for various tasks. And any plant that has developed more extensive movement would therefore also be able to move a "heart".